# Hibernate criteria with a combination of AND/OR

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-restrictions

I have to build a condition as below in the code.  The number of conditions added as a mix of AND/OR may vary with the same parameters.

```
WHERE ( (name=? AND number=?) ) OR ( (name=? AND number=?) ) OR (...) OR (...)
```

I tried below code in a loop -- not working as expected:

```
someList.forEach(item -> {
    SimpleExpression nameExp = Restrictions.eq("name", item.getName());
    SimpleExpression numberExp = Restrictions.eq("number", item.getNumber());
    Criterion criterion = Restrictions.and(nameExp, numberExp);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.or(criterion));
}
```

With the code above, I am getting the output with AND in between the first condition and the second. I want OR between conditions 1 and 2.

```
WHERE ( (name=? AND number=?) ) AND ( (name=? AND number=?) )
```

How do I build the condition as mentioned at the top using the criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You collect the criterions to a list and finally invoke `criteria.add(Restrictions.or(list))`.

Comment: Thank you, with your suggested tip I was able to build my criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for the general audience, based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64168194/1807836) from Christian Beikov.

I have added additional conditions to my criteria to spruce up the solution.

```
criteria.add(
    Restrictions.or(
            Restrictions.and(criterionListB.toArray(new Criterion[0])),
            Restrictions.or(criterionListA.toArray(new Criterion[0]))
));
```

This code evaluates to a mix of AND/OR operations as below:

```
(
  (
    (name = ? AND number = ?) OR (name = ? AND number = ?)
  ) 
  OR 
  (
    (id = ? AND email = ?)
  )
)
```